# Dynamically name class on rails view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an each loop and I want to use the index var to name dynamically
I have tried this but didn't work.

```
<% (0..4).each do |i| %>
<div id="item-<%= #{i} %>" class="hold-button">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<% (0..4).each do |i| %>
  <div id="item-<%= "#{i}" %>" class="hold-button">
<% end %>
```

or

```
<% (0..4).each do |i| %>
  <div id="item-<%= i %>" class="hold-button">
<% end %>
```

Remember:  #{} is used for embedded variable into strings. That's why your code doesn't work.

Comment: Just remember to use <% end %> as well, not shown in the source here

Answer (score 0):

You created a comment, not a string, this should work:

```
<div id="item-<%= "#{i}" %>" class="hold-button">
```

as should this:

```
<div id="item-<%= i %>" class="hold-button">
```

But personally, I would take an entirely different approach, since this code-snippet is not very Rails-like. Depending on your exact needs, you should check out the [content_tag](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TagHelper.html#method-i-content_tag)-, the [content_tag_for](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/RecordTagHelper.html#method-i-content_tag_for)- or the [div_for](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/RecordTagHelper.html#method-i-div_for)-helper_methods, because I have the feeling, that they will help you get the actual job done in an easier way.